# Next JS with WordPress Deployment URL issue

Tags: node.js, wordpress, ubuntu, deployment, next.js

I've created a project in Next JS and now I want to deploy it on my domain. Let's call it mydomain.com

The website is running on Ubuntu Apache2

I already have a WordPress website running on mydomain.com. But for mydomain.com/docs I have created the project in Next JS.

Now this can be acheived by uploading the build folder to (/var/www/html/docs).

But the problem is I want some URLs to take mydomain.com as base URL.

What I mean is I want some URLs to be mydomain.com/docs/page && mydomain.com/page

Is this even possible?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath

Comment: I know how to set the basepath. But how'll I solve the problem then?